# the time taken to read a file

Tags: file-access, benchmarking

I have a question. How long time does it takes to read a 2 mb file, which is fragmented in 2?

If the rotational delay is 4300 rpm
And the seektime is 10 ms
the transfer time is 10 mb/s
and the controller overhead is 0,5 ms.

My calculation is:

```
2*(10 ms + 7 ms (<-rotational delay) + 0,5 ms + 200 ms (<-transfer time))
```

Is this the right answer or have I done something wrong?

Comment: Wow, in real world we just use a high-resolution clock to measure how long it actually takes.

Comment: What about various caches between the file on disk and the read function?

Answer (score 1):

> Disk Access Time = Seek time +
>   Rotational Latency + Transfer time +
>   Controller Time + Queueing Delay(if
>   any)

So, get back to your book and find the correct answer.